# Item is not defined when creating folders by with_items

Tags: ansible

I want to create a folder structure with variables provided:

```
---
- name: Create project root
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ root_path }}{{ project_name }}"
- name: Create additional folders
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ root_path }}{{ project_name }}/{{ item }}"
    with_items:
       - production
       - logs
       - media
```

`root_path` is a default variable and `project_name` provided by extra variable. First task work fine but next one throw `"ERROR! 'item' is undefined"`. I tried move `item` from string, but it'll throw a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a minor indentation problem, that's why your task fails. `with_items:` should be at `file:`'s indent. Adjust it like this:

```
---
- name: Create project root
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ root_path }}{{ project_name }}"
- name: Create additional folders
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ root_path }}{{ project_name }}/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - production
     - logs
     - media
```

Comment: oh gosh thanks! How can I miss it, it is my firs experience with ansible :)

Comment: It happens. Have in mind that indentation is really important in Ansible. I hope you enjoy it, it's a very powerful tool.